# RecyclerView Listview doesn't populate when the activity loads but populates on pressing back button (sometimes on multiple backpress)

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'am using firebase as my database. My recyclerview dosen't populate when the activity loads first time, but it populate after backpress action sometimes multiple backpress.

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//Recycler Contact list variables
private RecyclerView mContactList;

//Firebase Variables

private DatabaseReference rDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ContactList,ContactListViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

//Request Contact Constant
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

private Long contactId;
private Uri downloadUrl = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        //do your check here
        mayRequestContacts();
    }

    //initialize Recycler view
    mContactList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    mContactList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mContactList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

   //initialize UI elements
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View headView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView uName = (TextView)headView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    ImageView dPhoto = (ImageView)headView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView mEmail = (TextView)headView.findViewById(R.id.uEmail);

    //initialize Firebase variables
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    rDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child(user.getDisplayName()).child("contacts");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    if (user != null) {
        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
        System.out.println(name);
        if(name!=null) {
            uName.setText(name);
            mEmail.setText(email);
        }
        if(photoUrl!=null){


            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(photoUrl)
                    .into(dPhoto);
        }

        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.

    }

    //initialize FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ContactList, ContactListViewHolder>(

            ContactList.class,
            R.layout.contact_list_row,
            ContactListViewHolder.class,
            rDatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ContactListViewHolder viewHolder, ContactList model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());

        }

    };

    mContactList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);        //set adapter for recycler view

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);   //instantiate toolbar

    //initialize floating action button
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with add contact or agenda", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    //initialize navigation drawer
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();


    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); //listen if any item selected




}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_importContacts) {
        // Handle the Import Contacts Action

        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Importing Contacts", true);

        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                try {


                    //user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); //Get the currently logged in user information
                    //Uid = user.getUid();    //Get User ID
                    //UName = user.getDisplayName();

                    //Initialize cursor to import contacts
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);

                    assert cur != null;
                    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                            //Get current Contact ID
                            contactId=cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                            //Get current Contact Name
                            String cName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                            //Get Current Contact URI
                            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

                            //Get Current Contact Photo Uri
                            Uri displayPhotoUri=null;
                            if(Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO)!=null){
                                displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);

                            }
                           try {
                                AssetFileDescriptor fd =
                                        getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // return null;
                            }

                            if(contactId!=null && cName!=null && displayPhotoUri!=null){

                                boolean flag = true;

                                Cursor emailCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {contactId.toString()}, null);

                                if(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))  <=0){
                                    flag = false;
                                }
                                else{

                                    //Import Contact Photo

                                    StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("users/"+user.getUid()+"/"+contactId+"/contactPhoto").child(displayPhotoUri.getLastPathSegment());
                                    filepath.putFile(displayPhotoUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {


                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                            // System.out.println(photoUri.toString()); //debug point

                                            downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                            rDatabase.child(contactId.toString()).child("photoUrl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                        }
                                    });

                                    //Import Contact Email ID if Any
                                    assert emailCursor != null;
                                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext())
                                    {
                                        String cEmail = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                                        int type = emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                                        rDatabase.child(contactId.toString()).child("email").setValue(cEmail);
                                    }
                                    emailCursor.close();

                                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                        new String[]{contactId.toString()}, null);
                                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    //Import Contact Phone No.
                                    rDatabase.child(contactId.toString()).child("phone").setValue(phoneNo);
                                    //Import Contact Name
                                        rDatabase.child(contactId.toString()).child("name").setValue(cName);

                                    }
                                pCur.close();

                            }}

                        }
                    }   cur.close();

                    Thread.sleep(10000);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    return;

                }

                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

            }

        }).start();




    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

        mAuth.signOut();    //Log out user method

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

//Method to request contacts (Required for API 23 and greater)
private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Permission Granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //File write logic here
            return true;
        }
    } else {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    return false;
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); //Listen to current user Login status

    mContactList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter); //Set adapter for contact list recycler view

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

//ViewHolder for ContactList Recycler View
public static class ContactListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    TextView contact_Name;
    TextView contact_Phone;

    public ContactListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name){

        contact_Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ContactName);
        contact_Name.setText(name);
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){

        contact_Phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ContactPhone);
        contact_Phone.setText(phone);
    }
}
```

}

Adapter class

```
public class ContactList {

private String name;
private String phone;

public ContactList(){}

public ContactList(String name, String phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="neeti.contactapp.HomeActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/contact_list"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

contact_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ContactName"
    android:textColor="@color/ContactName"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ContactPhone"
    android:layout_below="@id/ContactName"
    android:textColor="@color/ContactPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
and then set the adapter as:

```
mContactList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!